# How to setup Popover views to dismiss properly

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

After some work I've got a popover view displaying a custom uiview inside of it appearing properly. 
When you tap outside of the popover view it dismisses as expected, however I'd also like it to dismiss when a button inside it is tapped, is there any one who can help me with that? Struggling to find a concise guide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To dismiss the popover manually, you'll need to keep a reference to it.  A good place would be in the view controller that shows the popover.

To have the button inside the content view controller tell the original view controller (that presented the popover) to dismiss the popover, two of the possible ways are delegate+protocol or NSNotificationCenter.

The example code below uses [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In the .h of the view controller that presents the popover ("PresenterViewController"), add a property for the popoverViewController:

```
@interface PresenterViewController : UIViewController {
    ...
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}    
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@end
```

In the .m of PresenterViewController:

```
@synthesize popoverController;
...
- (void)showPopover
{
    if (self.popoverController == nil)
    {
        ContentFooViewController *content = 
            [[ContentFooViewController alloc] init];
        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
            initWithContentViewController:content];
        [content release];
        self.popoverController = popover;
        [popover release];

        // Listen for the "done" notification which will be posted
        // by the button in the content view controller.
        // When the notification is received, 
        // call the contentFooViewControllerDone: method...
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(contentFooViewControllerDone:)
            name:@"contentFooViewControllerDone" 
            object:popoverController.contentViewController];
    }

    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:...
      // OR
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:...
}

- (void)contentFooViewControllerDone:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Button in content view controller was tapped, dismiss popover...
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    //stop listening for notifications and release popoverController...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [popoverController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

In the content view controller, implement the button tap method as follows:

```
- (IBAction)dismissButtonTapped
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"contentFooViewControllerDone" object:self];
}
```

Comment: One caveat to this approach is if you close the popover by tapping outside of it, it will never be dismissed properly since you still have a reference to it. This is fine if you don't mind keeping an extra view controller around, but typically memory is at a premium and you don't want to do this. So, you should also use `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` to set the property to nil.

Comment: This is great - for others out there also note that Apple discourages having a button simply to close a popover. It's likely that your application does something else with that button as well, which is just fine. :)

Comment: @AnnaKarenina. hi, is there a way to check if the nsnotificationcenter has not been deallocated yet? I tried this approach but it seems like the flow doesn't go through the -(void)dealloc{} part after the nsnotification observer is triggered.