# Loading a new UIView over the rootUIView on UIButton click from UIPopovercontroller

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

My application is very simple and i am not using the splitview controller. 
My question is .. how can i load a new uiview over my root view controller on UIButton click from a popovercontroller view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the root view controller first dismiss the popover when the button is pressed in the popover and then you can present the new view from the root view controller.

For details on how to do the dismissal of the popover using a button inside the popver, see my previous answer ["How to setup Popover views to dismiss properly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937270/how-to-setup-popover-views-to-dismiss-properly/4938922#4938922).

The main idea is:

> To dismiss the popover manually,
>   you'll need to keep a reference to it.
>   A good place would be in the view
>   controller that shows the popover.
>
> To have the button inside the content
>   view controller tell the original view
>   controller (that presented the
>   popover) to dismiss the popover, two
>   of the possible ways are
>   delegate+protocol or
>   NSNotificationCenter.

In that previous answer, PresenterViewController is your root view controller (the one that presents the popover).

The difference in your case will be in the contentFooViewControllerDone method (which you would put in your root view controller):

```
- (void)contentFooViewControllerDone:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Button in content view controller was tapped, dismiss popover...
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    // Load new view here...
    // Note: If intending to use presentModalViewController 
    // (instead of addSubView), you might need to set animated to NO
    // for above popover dismissal (otherwise presentModal will do nothing) 
    // or use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay to present new 
    // view controller to animate both dismiss and present.
}
```

Comment: @aBitObvious, But i need a button action code to load a uiview over my rootViewController.

Comment: You are presenting a popover controller from the root view controller, right?  In the content view controller, you have a button?  Did you create the button in IB or programmatically?  Not sure what you are asking by "need a button action code".  What have you got so far?

Comment: @aBitObvious, yes correct ..and that popover has a UIButton which is created in interface builder. and when i click on the button i need to open a new uiview over my root view. I tried to run the pushviewcontroller code on it. But no success.

Comment: That's what this answer and the previous linked answer shows how to do.  You need to first dismiss the popover and then push from the _root view controller_ (not in the button action method).  Try following the steps in the previous linked answer and this one.

Comment: You would put the pushViewController call in the contentFooViewControllerDone method shown above (which goes in your root view controller).

Comment: @aBitObvious, i tesed the given code today. Now it's loading the view but the problem is that it's not loading the content of that view. I added this code to my root view and button action on the popovercontroller

Comment: The content of what view?  The popover or the view you want to push after the popover is dismissed?  In contentFooViewControllerDone, why didn't you add the pushViewController call?  Instead of adding code in another answer, you should edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(contentFooViewControllerDone:)
            name:@"contentFooViewControllerDone" 
            object:popoverController.contentViewController];



- (void)contentFooViewControllerDone:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Button in content view controller was tapped, dismiss popover...
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    //stop listening for notifications and release popoverController...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [popoverController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)dismissButtonTapped
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"contentFooViewControllerDone" object:self];
}
```